# Different TAX rule for diffent country

Tags: magento-1.9

i'm trying to create a taxe rules that for same products add different tax.

The price of my products is whitout tax (excludind tax) for example 100 €

I would like that for example for my customer in Italy (since we are in italy) they pay 100+Tax(22%), instead my customer in Spain i would like they pay just 100 €

Can you help me to create these tax rules

Thank you very much
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

Check here: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/tax/tax-rules.html
If you still have problems, please leave a comment.

Comment: Need to add a new tax rate and assigne the tax rate to a specific country

Comment: Check this: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-create-tax-rule-magento